# Mdichild form lags when I move it

Tags: c#

My main form's mdichild form lags when I move it.
This is my code that loads mdi child form when I click on a button.

```
Form2 a =new Form2();
a.Mdiparent=this;
a.show();
```

When I click on that button ,form loads.But when I want to change it's place on my mdiparent form,it lags

Comment: You have not given enough information for someone to provide a proper answer. You need to post relevant code that you think might be making the form lag.

Comment: I edit my post.Now what is your answer?thank you!

Comment: Is there happening anything else when you open the form? If so, there might be something running (a loop or something) which slows the application down, thus creating lag. Also: is your PC old? If it's really old it might lag just because it doesn't have enough juice to do it flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

If your using MDI forms then remove control box of Child form, so user will not move it

Comment: Removing the control box won't stop the user from moving it if it isn't maximized. Also, I think he wants to know WHY it is lagging and how he can fix that, while still able to move it.

Comment: Use this one and check form.Dock = DockStyle.Fill